# VLC Player; User Interface completely altered because Qt scaling is broken

Tags: applications, qt

[image]Just installed VLC from the Elementary appstore. The user interface shows huge buttons, very small text font, and over-sized menu windows. Can it be fixed?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This situation with VLC appeared on my Elementary-Os too.

I found a solution in the [Ubuntu forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041629/vlc-shows-very-big-icons-and-is-unusable) and [videolan forum](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=144714)

So, what you can do is, open a terminal and open the environment file:

> sudo nano /etc/environment

and add a line to it:

> QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0

Save it and reboot your computer.

This helped me getting VLC in the right scaling.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to **Tools** and then **Customize** **Interface**...

[image]

... is the **Big Button** button checked under **Toolbar Elements**?

[image]

Comment: Nop. See my edited question, and the image added